# Why my action is not loaded when I click on a button?

Tags: symfony, controller, onclick, action

I wanted to create a button that delete a pupil. But I have a problem, my button doesn't launch the deleteAction in my controller.

My controller :

```
public function deleteAction(Eleve $id, $schoolId)
{
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('WCSCantineBundle:Lunch');
    $pupil = $repository->findOneBy(array(
        'eleve' => $id
    ));
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->remove($pupil);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('wcs_cantine_todayList', array('schoolId' => $schoolId)));
}
```

My route :

```
delete_pupil:
path:     /
defaults: { _controller: "WCSCantineBundle:CanteenManager:delete" }
```

My button (in my view) :

```
<a href="{{ path('delete_pupil', { 'id': lunch.eleve.id, 'schoolId': ecole.id }) }}">Désinscrire</a>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think, you forgot the word "Action" at the end of `WCSCantineBundle:CanteenManager:delete` in your route.

Comment: I will try but normally it works without like this route : 
wcs_cantine_todayList:
    path:     /todayList/{schoolId}
    defaults: { _controller: "WCSCantineBundle:CanteenManager:todayList" }

To launch the todayListAction

Comment: Yes, you are right. `Action` is appended automatically (what a weird scripting language). Did you checked, if the method `deleteAction` is called if you remove the parameters?

Comment: @MartinZabel In Symfony2 routes are defined by [logical groupings](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#controller-naming-pattern), and the suffixes for classes and method names in those groupings are omitted for brevity. So the logical name of `WCSCantineBundle:CanteenManager:delete` refers to the `deleteAction` method of the `CanteenManagerController` class in the `WCSCantine` bundle.

Comment: What specific error are receiving when you click your button to access your route?

Comment: You have no parameters in your route so they not pass automatically to your function, you can retrieve them from request only.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function deleteAction(Eleve $id, $schoolId)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $pupil = $em->getRepository('WCSCantineBundle:Lunch')->findOneBy(array('eleve' => $id));

    $em->remove($pupil);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('wcs_cantine_todayList', array('schoolId' => $schoolId)));
}
```

your code fails because the doctrine entity manager has no clue about what $pupil is since there is two different instances of entity managers, the above code is short hand for removing pupil, but you can change it as needed as long as the entity manager 'knows' about the entity

Comment: You may be right, but where is the actual code difference? You saved the result of `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()` into the variable `em` to use it again later on. But, then you retrieved `pupil` the same way as the OP.

Comment: OP created entity manager twice, the first one is aware of $pupil, the second one is not aware, flush() was called on the second one and hence the remove function had no effect on the database

Answer (score 0):

I did it and it works.

My controller :

```
public function deleteAction($id, $schoolId)
{
    $dateNow = new \DateTime();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $lunches = $em->getRepository('WCSCantineBundle:Lunch')->findBy(array(
        'eleve' => $id,
        'date' => $dateNow
    ));
    foreach ($lunches as $lunch) {
        $em->remove($lunch);
    }
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('wcs_cantine_todayList', array('schoolId' => $schoolId)));
}
```

My route :

```
delete_pupil:
path:     /todayList/{schoolId}/{id}
defaults: { _controller: "WCSCantineBundle:CanteenManager:delete" }
methods: [GET, DELETE]
```

And my view :

```
<a href="{{ path('delete_pupil', {'id': lunch.eleve.id, 'schoolId': ecole.id }) }}">Désinscrire</a>
```

I missed to pass my arguments in my route with slashes : /todayList/{schoolId}/{id}
I thank everybody for your help.